# Mongoose TypeError: Schema is not a constructor I've tried solutions from other posts but no work

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I am practicing with React.js and MongoDb, I tried to save some data using Mongoose but it keeps returning TypeError: Schema is not a constructor.

I tested it by using Postman not through the brower with React.js.

I have checked many of similar Stackoverflow posts but could not figure out why my code does not work.

Here is my code for Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ContactData", ContactSchema);
```

And here is my POST request:

```
router.post("/create_contact", (req, res) => {
  const { name, number } = req.body

  let contact = new ContactData(
    name,
    number
  );

  contact.save((error, contact) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.error(error);
    }

    return res.json(contact);
  });
});
```

No problems found with connecting to local MongoDb and running Express server.

What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **new** keyword when instantiating a new schema:

```
const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but, have you imported ContactData model in your route file?

Comment: I also have tried this and still get the error. And @vitomadio yes I have.